# jquery 'on change' fires despite clicked button is classed 'active'

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I made a bootstrap form  and am using jquery to handle all the clicks in the form.

```
<form class="form">
    <div id="one" class="btn-group input-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active">
        <input id="a" type="radio" />Choice A</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs ">
        <input id="b" type="radio" />Choice B</label>
    </div>
 </form>

<script>
$("#one").on("change",  function(e){
    if (e.target.id=="a"){
        console.log("a")
    }else{
        console.log("b")
    } 
});
</script>
```

The button group is a radio style, with only one button active. 
Goal is to only execute the callback function if a new button is clicked.

Choice A is active by default via the class active. I was expecting that clicking this button would not fire an event since nothing is changed. But the callback function in the jquery does get executed when clicking Choice A for the first time after the page has loaded.
After you clicked a button once, it behaves as expected, only logging a or b if it is not active.

Is there a way to setup the html so that clicking the "active" choice does not trigger the jquery on change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#one input").on("change",  function(e){
    if ($(this).attr('id')=="a"){
        console.log("a")
    }else{
        console.log("b")
    } 
});
```

and you can add class for label using

```
 $('#one label').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('label').addClass('active');
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JLubs/57/)

Comment: Regretfully, changing the selector to include "input" still leads to an event being triggered when clicking choice A for the first time after the page has loaded.

Comment: thanks! That would have worked. In the end I simply added checked="checked" attribute to the input tag. That solved the problem.